# Proof for the existence of a bijection between $\boldsymbol{m}\cdot\boldsymbol{n}$ and $\boldsymbol{m}\times\boldsymbol{n}$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, solution-verification

I am proving the following theorem:

> For all $\boldsymbol{m},\boldsymbol{n} \in \mathbb{N}$, there exists a bijection between the natural number $\boldsymbol{m} \cdot \boldsymbol{n}$ and the Cartesian product $\boldsymbol{m} \times \boldsymbol{n}$.

The following theorem about addition is ready to use:

> For all $\boldsymbol{m},\boldsymbol{n} \in \mathbb{N}$, there exists a bijection between the set $\boldsymbol{m} + \boldsymbol{n}$ and $\left(\boldsymbol{m}\times \left\{\boldsymbol{0}\right\}\right) \cup \left(\boldsymbol{n}\times \left\{\boldsymbol{1}\right\}\right)$.

It is also assumed that you know the following theorem:

> For all $\boldsymbol{n} \in \mathbb{N}$, $\boldsymbol{n} \not\in \boldsymbol{n}$.

Below is my proof.

Define a set
\begin{equation*}
A = \left\{\boldsymbol{n}\in\mathbb{N}: \boldsymbol{m} \in \mathbb{N} \textrm{ and there exists a bijection between $\boldsymbol{m} \cdot \boldsymbol{n}$ and $\boldsymbol{m} \times \boldsymbol{n}$}\right\},
\end{equation*}
where $\boldsymbol{m}$ is an arbitrary fixed element of $\mathbb{N}$, which can be quantified on universally later due to its arbitrariness. First consider the case $\boldsymbol{n} = \boldsymbol{0}$. According to the definition of multiplication,
\begin{equation*}
\boldsymbol{m} \cdot \boldsymbol{0} = \boldsymbol{0} = \emptyset.
\end{equation*}
Also, we have the following relation:
\begin{equation*}
\boldsymbol{m} \times \boldsymbol{0} = \boldsymbol{m} \times \emptyset = \emptyset.
\end{equation*}
There exists a bijection $f: \emptyset \to \emptyset$. Thus, the relation $\boldsymbol{0} \in A$ holds. Now assume that $\boldsymbol{n} \in A$. That is, there exists a bijection
\begin{equation*}
f: \boldsymbol{m} \cdot \boldsymbol{n} \to \boldsymbol{m} \times \boldsymbol{n}.
\end{equation*}
We would like to prove that there exists a bijection $z: \boldsymbol{m} \cdot \boldsymbol{n}^{+} \to \boldsymbol{m} \times \boldsymbol{n}^{+}$. According to the definition of $\boldsymbol{n}^{+}$, we have
\begin{equation*}
\boldsymbol{m} \times \boldsymbol{n}^{+} = \boldsymbol{m} \times \left(\boldsymbol{n} \cup \left\{ \boldsymbol{n} \right\}\right) = \left(\boldsymbol{m} \times \boldsymbol{n}\right) \cup \left(\boldsymbol{m} \times \left\{\boldsymbol{n}\right\}\right),
\end{equation*}
where the two sets $\boldsymbol{m} \times \boldsymbol{n}$ and $\boldsymbol{m} \times \left\{\boldsymbol{n}\right\}$ are disjoint, as $\boldsymbol{n} \not\in \boldsymbol{n}$. According to the definition of multiplication, we have
\begin{equation*}
\boldsymbol{m} \cdot \boldsymbol{n}^{+} = \boldsymbol{m} \cdot \boldsymbol{n} + \boldsymbol{m}.
\end{equation*}
From the theorem involving addition, we know that there exists the following bijection:
\begin{equation*}
g: \left(\boldsymbol{m}\cdot\boldsymbol{n} + \boldsymbol{m}\right) \to \left(\boldsymbol{m}\cdot\boldsymbol{n} \times \left\{\boldsymbol{0}\right\}\right) \cup \left(\boldsymbol{m}\times\left\{\boldsymbol{1}\right\}\right).
\end{equation*}
It is obvious that there exists a bijection $h: \boldsymbol{m}\times\left\{\boldsymbol{1}\right\} \to \boldsymbol{m} \times \left\{\boldsymbol{n}\right\}$.

We may define a function $s: \left(\boldsymbol{m}\cdot\boldsymbol{n} \times \left\{\boldsymbol{0}\right\}\right) \cup \left(\boldsymbol{m}\times\left\{\boldsymbol{1}\right\}\right) \to \left(\boldsymbol{m} \times \boldsymbol{n}\right) \cup \left(\boldsymbol{m} \times \left\{\boldsymbol{n}\right\}\right)$ as follows:
\begin{equation*}
s\left(\boldsymbol{x}\right) = 
\begin{cases}
f\left(\boldsymbol{t}\right),\ \boldsymbol{t} \in \boldsymbol{m}\cdot\boldsymbol{n} \textrm{ and } \left(\boldsymbol{t},\boldsymbol{0}\right) = \boldsymbol{x}\\
h\left(\boldsymbol{x}\right),\ \boldsymbol{x} \in \boldsymbol{m}\times\left\{\boldsymbol{1}\right\}
\end{cases}.
\end{equation*}
As both $f$ and $h$ are bijections, $s$ is also a bijection. So far, we may conclude
\begin{equation*}
g: \boldsymbol{m}\cdot\boldsymbol{n}^{+} \to \left(\boldsymbol{m}\cdot\boldsymbol{n} \times \left\{\boldsymbol{0}\right\}\right) \cup \left(\boldsymbol{m}\times\left\{\boldsymbol{1}\right\}\right)
\end{equation*}
is a bijection and
\begin{equation*}
s: \left(\boldsymbol{m}\cdot\boldsymbol{n} \times \left\{\boldsymbol{0}\right\}\right) \cup \left(\boldsymbol{m}\times\left\{\boldsymbol{1}\right\}\right) \to \boldsymbol{m}\times\boldsymbol{n}^{+}
\end{equation*}
is also a bijection. As a result, the function $s \circ g$ is a bijection.

Up to now, we have proved that $\boldsymbol{n} \in A$ and if $\boldsymbol{n} \in A$, then $\boldsymbol{n}^{+} \in A$. Thus we may conclude
\begin{equation*}
A = \mathbb{N}.
\end{equation*}

P.S. This is an exercise from the book Classic Set Theory by D.C. Goldrei. Solution is not provided in the book. I proved it myself and would like to know if it is a good proof.

Comment: I don't understand your definition of $A$ - should it be $\{{\bf n}\in\mathbb{N}:\color{red}{\forall}{\bf m}\in\mathbb{N}...\}$?

Comment: OK, but then you need to precede your definition of $A$ by fixing ${\bf m}$. At some point you actually have to specify how ${\bf m}$ is being introduced, and what depends on what.

Comment: @NoahSchweber OK. Good comments. Actually fixing $\boldsymbol{m} \in \mathbb{N}$ is the step before you quantify on it. So indeed, I should state the thought in the proof. Thanks.